# Groovy - how to convert a String which is in 2 lines to an ArrayList of elements where each line from string is one element

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to find a way to convert a String which is in 2 lines into a List or an Arraylist in Groovy on Jenkins.

String is in below format

```
"test-st-1
test-st-2"
```

And I am trying to convert it in to a list `["test-st-1","test-st-2"]`

I tried to do tolist() and what I got was

```
[t, e, s, t, -, s, t, -, 1,  , 
, t, e, s, t, -, s, t, -, 2,  , 
]
```

Please advise if there are methods or ways that I can use to fulfill this requirement.

Long story Why I am doing this is I have a requirement where I need to identify the namespace names in format test-st-[1-12] from Kubernetes so when I query namespaces using kubectl I get the list of names in that particular String format above and I need to create new namespaces with a name following the number sequence. If there are already namespaces test-st-1, test-st-3 then I need to create namespace test-st-2 and then continue sequence from test-st-4.
I have a definite list that has namespaces from test-st-[1-12]. So I wanted to do an intersect of 2 lists(1. list of namespaces already created 2. definite list) and so on to get a new list based on which I will iterate to get the namespace name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `readLines` to split a string at line breaks:

```
"a\nb".readLines()
// → [a, b]
```